# Windows service (Client) is communicating with C# Web API (Server). I want to check the server is online or not at a time interval

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, windows-services

If the C# server is offline then Windows Service will storage the data in SQLite and when the server is back online it will process the data. I can use a trimmer to check the server is online in every 5-10 sec. I wonder is there any better approach to deal with this kind of scenario?

Comment: So, you run a test and the server is online. You then send data and it fails. Why? Because *between* the check and sending the data the server failed, or the network had an issue, etc. No amount of pre-checking can save you. You always need to account for the possibility of failure when asking the server to *actually* do some work for you. What may be more useful is to look at some form of queueing system (e.g. MSMQ) so that you can effectively ignore whether the "other end" of your intended communication is online at the same time that you are.

Answer (score 0):

The right solution for scheduling simple processes is the **Windows Task Scheduler**.

> **If you're writing a Windows Service that runs a timer, you should re-evaluate your solution. ..**

–Jon Galloway, ASP.NET MVC community program manager, author, part time superhero

[//TODONT: Use a Windows Service just to run a scheduled process](https://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/428303)

Comment: Hi, @Sumana, please let us know if you have  updated information on this issue.